# Read messages from client TCP IP in react-native

Tags: javascript, python, react-native, tcp, tcpclient

I am facing one weird problem with my application I am able to make connection as a client to the TCP IP this is the code that I am using in Javascript:

```
const cn = TcpSocket.createConnection({
  port: 27015,
  host: '192.168.0.10',
  localAddress: '192.168.0.11',
});
cn.on('data', res => {
  cn.write('\x80\x00\x00');
});
cn.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log('imce error: ', error);
});
cn.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Connection closed!');
});
```

but the problem appears when I receive message from server and for each message I should send back acknowledgment like this **cn.write('\x80\x00\x00');** and it goes till somewhere and then I don't receive messages from server, while weird part is here I made two other scripts that works very good one in Python and one in PHP both of them have same logic meaning make connection and then write data as a client but here the only difference is that when I read data I read it with infinite loop you can see both examples, now I am wondering does it have any chance this **cn.on('data', with callback here)** in Javascript to make it like in both examples to store it in one variable everytime that has new message and then to run infinite loop also in Javascript.

Python example:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.15', 27015)
print(sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.connect(server_address)
full_msg = ''
try:
    # Send data
    message = '\x06\x01\x0C\x19\x40\x49\x07\x56\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00'
    print(sys.stderr, 'sending amount "%s"' % message)
    sock.sendall(message)

    while True:
            msg = sock.recv(1024)
            if len(msg) <= 0:
                    break
            full_msg += msg
            ackmsg = '\x80\x00\x00'
            print(sys.stderr, 'sending ack "%s"' % message)
            sock.sendall(ackmsg)
finally:
    print(sys.stderr, 'closing socket')
sock.close()
```

PHP example:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

if(!is_resource($socket)) onSocketFailure("Failed to create socket");

socket_connect($socket, "192.168.0.10", 27015) or onSocketFailure("Failed to connect to chat.stackoverflow.com:6667", $socket);

socket_write($socket, "\x06\x01\x0C\x19\x40\x49\x07\x56\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00");

while(true) {
    $line = socket_read($socket, 1024);
    error_log(strlen($line));
    if(strlen($line) <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    error_log($line);
    socket_write($socket, "\x80\x00\x00");

}

socket_close($socket);
```